# Preg_match pattern with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

As I am trying from couple of hrs. Below is the string.

```
Contact: <sip:6185347017@202.65.142.187:54163>
To: "915454454544"<sip:915454454544@103.24.124.2>
From: "6185347017"<sip:6185347017@103.24.124.2>;tag=8237b810
Call-ID: OTNhYzMxZDFmOThmMGI1ZmIxNmE3OGM2MGZkOTFkZTc.
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, NOTIFY, MESSAGE, SUBSCRIBE, INFO
Content-Type: application/sdp
Proxy-Authorization: Digest     username="6185347017",realm="103.24.124.2",nonce="5f69d948-0639-11e3-8d11-238fc92f6fd0",uri="s      ip:915454454544@103.24.124.2",response="39a1d1688114ec06d5ccd49bba1b4883",cnonce="3c76312b0377    9cdf9c9aa4d3f2a1962a",nc=00000001,qop=auth,algorithm=MD5
User-Agent: eyeBeam release 1102q stamp 51814
Content-Length: 315
```

I want to get `To:` value and `From:` value and bottom `content-Length`, We need those values.

Comment: Can you show us your progress? What regex you already tried?

Comment: It's pretty easy to do. Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
To\:\s(.*)|From\:\s(.*)|Content\-Length\:\s(.\*)
```

You will got your data in $1 $2 $3

Answer (score 1):

To get To or From : `(To|From): ["0-9<:@.>;a-zA-Z:=]+`
To get Content-Lengh : `Content-(l|L)ength: \d+`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nother way to do it using a positive lookahead:

```
(?=To|From)\w+:\s"(\d+)"|Content-Length:\s(\d+)
```

`$1` will contain your *To* and *From* values

`$2` will contain your *Content-Length* value

You can try it [HERE](http://regex101.com/r/tB1vY1)